# Button, Text Field, Label layout in GUI

Tags: java, swing, layout

I know this is a lot of code. I'm trying to get it so the layout is nicer, and I can't get anything to work.I want to get it so the HelpButton is bottom right, HelpField is bottom center, and the Clear button is bottom left.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame { //open class

private final JTextField HelpField, tField, uField, xField, yField, tPlusuField, tMinusuField, uDividedtField, uTimestField, xPlusyField, xMinusyField, yDividedxField, yTimesxField;

private final JLabel tLabel, uLabel, xLabel, yLabel, tPlusuLabel, tMinusuLabel, uDividedtLabel, uTimestLabel, xPlusyLabel, xMinusyLabel, yDividedxLabel, yTimesxLabel; 

private final JButton doSimpleMath, Reset, HelpButton;

 public GUI() { //open 

   super("GUI");

   setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   JPanel panLeft = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

   tLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for t:");
   tField = new JTextField(2);
   add(tLabel);
   add(tField);


   uLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for u:");
   uField = new JTextField(2);
   add(uLabel);
   add(uField);


   xLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for x:");
   xField = new JTextField(2);
   add(xLabel);
   add(xField);


   yLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for y:");
   yField = new JTextField(2);
   add(yLabel);
   add(yField);


   doSimpleMath = new JButton("Do Simple Math");
   add(doSimpleMath);

   Reset = new JButton("Reset");
   add(Reset);

   HelpButton = new JButton("Help");
   add(HelpButton);


   ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
   doSimpleMath.addActionListener(handler);
   Reset.addActionListener(handler);
   HelpButton.addActionListener(handler);

   HelpField = new JTextField(40);
   add(HelpField);
   HelpField.setEditable(false);


   tPlusuLabel = new JLabel("t + u =");
   tPlusuField = new JTextField(5);
   tPlusuField.setEditable(false);
   add(tPlusuLabel);
   add(tPlusuField);

   tMinusuLabel = new JLabel("t - u =");
   tMinusuField = new JTextField(5);
   tMinusuField.setEditable(false);
   add(tMinusuLabel);
   add(tMinusuField);

   uDividedtLabel = new JLabel("u / t =");
   uDividedtField = new JTextField(5);
   uDividedtField.setEditable(false);
   add(uDividedtLabel);
   add(uDividedtField);

  uTimestLabel = new JLabel("u * t =");
  uTimestField = new JTextField(5);
  uTimestField.setEditable(false);
  add(uTimestLabel);
  add(uTimestField);

  xPlusyLabel = new JLabel("x + y =");
  xPlusyField = new JTextField(5);
  xPlusyField.setEditable(false);
  add(xPlusyLabel);
  add(xPlusyField);

  xMinusyLabel = new JLabel("x - y =");
  xMinusyField = new JTextField(5);
  xMinusyField.setEditable(false);
  add(xMinusyLabel);
  add(xMinusyField);

  yDividedxLabel = new JLabel("y / x =");
  yDividedxField = new JTextField(5);
  yDividedxField.setEditable(false);
  add(yDividedxLabel);
  add(yDividedxField);

  yTimesxLabel = new JLabel("y * x =");
  yTimesxField = new JTextField(5);
  yTimesxField.setEditable(false);
  add(yTimesxLabel);
  add(yTimesxField);

 } // close

 private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { //open ButtonHandler

   @Override

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { //open actionPerformed

     if(event.getSource() == doSimpleMath){ //close if

       int t = Integer.parseInt(tField.getText()); //convert String to int 
       int u = Integer.parseInt(uField.getText());
       int x = Integer.parseInt(xField.getText());
       int y = Integer.parseInt(yField.getText());

       int tSumu = t + u; //define values
       int tMinusu = t - u;
       int uDividedt = t / u;
       int uTimest = u * t;
       int xSumy = x + y;
       int xMinusy = x - y;
       int yDividedx = y / x;
       int yTimesx = y * x;

       tPlusuField.setText(tSumu + " "); //disply output
       tMinusuField.setText(tMinusu + " ");  
       uDividedtField.setText(uDividedt + " "); 
       uTimestField.setText(uTimest + " "); 
       xPlusyField.setText(xSumy + " ");
       xMinusyField.setText(xMinusy + " ");
       yDividedxField.setText(yDividedx + " ");
       yTimesxField.setText(yTimesx + " ");

     } //close if 

     if (event.getSource() == Reset){ //open if

       tPlusuField.setText(""); //disply output
       tMinusuField.setText("");  
       uDividedtField.setText(""); 
       uTimestField.setText(""); 
       xPlusyField.setText("");
       xMinusyField.setText("");
       yDividedxField.setText("");
       yTimesxField.setText("");
       tField.setText("");
       uField.setText("");
       xField.setText("");
       yField.setText("");
       HelpField.setText("");

     } //close if 

     if (event.getSource() == HelpButton) { //open if 

       HelpField.setText("You Need Help.");

     } //close if 

   } // close actionPerformed

 }//close ButtonHandler
```

} // close class

Comment: Rather the trying to layout everything in a single container, use multiple containers, with different layout managers to achieve the individual results you're after and the combine them back together. If you use separate classes, it will also make it easier to isolate functionality

Answer (score 2):

Remember, you can use any number of containers and layouts which you can combine together to generate complex layouts, for example:

[image: Form]

```
public GUI() { //open 

    super("GUI");

    JPanel panLeft = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


    JPanel fields = new JPanel();
    JPanel actions = new JPanel();

    tLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for t:");
    tField = new JTextField(2);
    fields.add(tLabel);
    fields.add(tField);

    uLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for u:");
    uField = new JTextField(2);
    fields.add(uLabel);
    fields.add(uField);

    xLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for x:");
    xField = new JTextField(2);
    fields.add(xLabel);
    fields.add(xField);

    yLabel = new JLabel("Enter value you for y:");
    yField = new JTextField(2);
    fields.add(yLabel);
    fields.add(yField);

    doSimpleMath = new JButton("Do Simple Math");
    fields.add(doSimpleMath);

    HelpField = new JTextField(40);
    add(HelpField);
    HelpField.setEditable(false);

    Reset = new JButton("Reset");
    add(Reset);

    HelpButton = new JButton("Help");
    add(HelpButton);

    actions.add(Reset);
    actions.add(HelpField);
    actions.add(HelpButton);

    tPlusuLabel = new JLabel("t + u =");
    tPlusuField = new JTextField(5);
    tPlusuField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(tPlusuLabel);
    fields.add(tPlusuField);

    tMinusuLabel = new JLabel("t - u =");
    tMinusuField = new JTextField(5);
    tMinusuField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(tMinusuLabel);
    fields.add(tMinusuField);

    uDividedtLabel = new JLabel("u / t =");
    uDividedtField = new JTextField(5);
    uDividedtField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(uDividedtLabel);
    fields.add(uDividedtField);

    uTimestLabel = new JLabel("u * t =");
    uTimestField = new JTextField(5);
    uTimestField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(uTimestLabel);
    fields.add(uTimestField);

    xPlusyLabel = new JLabel("x + y =");
    xPlusyField = new JTextField(5);
    xPlusyField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(xPlusyLabel);
    fields.add(xPlusyField);

    xMinusyLabel = new JLabel("x - y =");
    xMinusyField = new JTextField(5);
    xMinusyField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(xMinusyLabel);
    fields.add(xMinusyField);

    yDividedxLabel = new JLabel("y / x =");
    yDividedxField = new JTextField(5);
    yDividedxField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(yDividedxLabel);
    fields.add(yDividedxField);

    yTimesxLabel = new JLabel("y * x =");
    yTimesxField = new JTextField(5);
    yTimesxField.setEditable(false);
    fields.add(yTimesxLabel);
    fields.add(yTimesxField);


    add(fields);
    add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

} // close
```

Take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

In your JFrame put a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). In the `SOUTH` of this put another BorderLayout. In this last BorderLayout put your components in `WEST`, `CENTER` and `EAST`.

Answer (score -1):

try using (new AbsoluteLayout()) in setLayout and assign x and y co-ordinate for every component. it'll be helpful..you can place your components wherever you want.